# Wait for firebase storage upload to finish before running code to get the download link - angular2 / ionic / angularfire2

Tags: ios, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, upload

I upload an image that gets taken with the camera, or photo library using `firebase`. The promise contains the relevant code:

```
fileEntry.file(function (file) {
  //var reader = new FileReader();
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (e) => {
    var dataURL = reader.result;

    let image       : string  = 'profile_' + self.username + '_' + square + '.jpg',
      storageRef  : any,
      parseUpload : any;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      storageRef       = firebase.storage().ref('/profile/' + self.username + '/' + image);
      parseUpload      = storageRef.putString(dataURL, 'data_url');

      parseUpload.on('state_changed', (_snapshot) => {
        // We could log the progress here IF necessary
        console.log('snapshot progess ' + _snapshot);
        },
        (_err) => {
           reject(_err);
           console.log(_err);
        },
        (success) => {
           resolve(parseUpload.snapshot);
        })
      }).then(value => {
        //this.af.list('/profile/' + self.username).push({ pic: image });
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
```

This code gets the download URL from firebase back in the page controller where the cameraservice was called:

```
presentActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: 'Choose source',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Camera',
          handler: () => {
            let itemArrayTwo = this.profComponents.toArray();
            this.cameraService.getMedia(this.optionsGetCamera, this.square).then(() => {

                let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('/profile/' + this.username + '/profile_' + this.username + '_' + this.square + '.jpg');
                  storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                    console.log(url);
                    this.myrenderer.setElementAttribute(itemArrayTwo[this.square - 1].nativeElement, 'src', url);
                    this.showSquare();
                  });

            }); //pass in square choice
            //this.myrenderer.setElementAttribute(this.itemArrayTwo[this.square - 1].nativeElement, 'src', 'block');
            console.log('camera clicked');
          }

          ...
```

The problem is, the function that returns the Download URL runs before the `parseUpload.on('state_ ...` is finished uploading. Example console output:

```
...

[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: 
            https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mane-4152c.appspot.com/o/profile%2Fjackson%2Fprofile_jackson_1.jpg?alt=media&token=85884da1-d9f1-4ffb-a4dd-a24ce9bdfbef
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[16:24:16]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object]

...
```

You can see that the downloadURL gets logged in the middle of the snapshot upload progress. There must be someway to wait for the firebase upload to finish before doing anything else.